how to open Android Application automatically when received FCM message
My app is receiving the notification but it's not opened alone here is the code I have:
public class MyFireBaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id";
    private static final String TAG = "FCM";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // Check if message contains a notification payload
        try {
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle() != null ? remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle() : "FCM Message";
            String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() != null ? remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody() : "";

            // Create notification
            NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background) // Set your notification icon here
                    .setAutoCancel(true); // Dismiss the notification when clicked

            // Create intent to launch MainActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // Add this flag to start the activity from a non-activity context
            intent.putExtra("notification_clicked", true); // You can pass additional data if needed

            // Set the intent as the action for the notification
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

            // Show the notification
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            createNotificationChannel(notificationManager);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
        }   }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error handling notification: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager notificationManager) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence channelName = "My Channel";
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}

and here is my payload
def sendPush(title, msg, registration_token, dataObject=None):
    message = messaging.MulticastMessage(
        notification = messaging.Notification(
            title=title,
            body=msg,
        ),
        data=dataObject,
        tokens=registration_token,
    )

I am trying to open my application automatically when fcm push message is received.

If you have new information to add to a question, don't leave it in a comment.  Instead, edit the question using the edit link at the bottom to revise your post.

"I am trying to open my application automatically when fcm push message is received"
You are discouraged from doing this
